# Sails lift in production mode not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, production-environment

When I try to lift sails app using
 `sails lift --prod` it gives error in production.js file. Saying that `Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected character '#'.
Line 12432 in .tmp/public/concat/production.js`

I search that and found it was comming from a js file from my assets which had

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

When I remove this line and try to do  sails lift --prod it get stucks in
[image]

Don't know what's the error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like your files are a bit out-of-whack for this project.  There shouldn't be an executable node file in your assets; it's not valid client-side javascript.  You can also run `sails lift --prod --verbose` to see what else is going on when you lift.

Comment: I tried as u suggested lifting sails with --verbose as I waited for about 8 minutes then it showed the sails lift logo. Don't know what was the problem but eventually sails lift was successfull.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can get even more debug output with using `--silly` instead off `--verbose`

Answer (score 0):

tasks->register->prod.js

comment one line

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('prod', [
        'compileAssets',
        'concat',
        // 'uglify',
        'cssmin',
        'sails-linker:prodJs',
        'sails-linker:prodStyles',
        'sails-linker:devTpl',
        'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
        'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
        'sails-linker:devTplJade'
    ]);
};
```

Don't know if this is good or bad but it finally lifted. [reference](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2441)